# How to disable an checkbox once a certain radio button is clicked.

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, forms

Want to disable the checkbox "animation" once the "3D" radio button is selected. and too un-disable once the "2D" is selected.

html code

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="createProject">
    <div class="projectForm">
      <table cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
          <td> Project Name </td>
          <td> <input type="text" name="projectName" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Project Description </td>
          <td> <textarea name="projectDesc" > </textarea> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Pipleline Type </td>
          <td> 
            <input type="radio" name="pipelineType" value="2d" id="2d" checked="checked" onclick="displayType"> 2D Pipleline <br>
            <input type="radio" name="pipelineType" value="3d" id="3d" onclick="displayType"> 3D Pipleline </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Project Roles </td>
          <td> <input type="checkbox" name="projectRoles" id="animation"value="Animation Clean Up"> Animation Clean Up  
            <input type="checkbox" name="projectRoles" value="Background Painting"> Background Painting 
            <input type="checkbox" name="projectRoles" value="Casting & Recording"> Casting & Recording
            <input type="checkbox" name="projectRoles" value="Color Styling"> Color Styling
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </script>
```

Im new at ember.js, I have the java code in the app.js. Would it be better if it was placed in another js file?

javascrirpt

```
function displayType() {

    if(document.getElementById('2d').checked) {
        document.getElementById('animation').disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('animation').disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: want something likethis -> http://jsfiddle.net/6x9NZ/95/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that you have forgotten to make your onclick calls into function calls:

```
onclick="displayType"
```

Needs to change to

```
onclick="displayType()"
```

Next, when I put your code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSV3p/), it was not finding the function because it was not in the global scope.  When I changed the function definition from:

```
function displayType() {
```

to:

```
window.displayType = function () {
```

it solved the problem.  This may be different depending on where you put your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to disable it:

```
document.getElementById('animation').removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand, pass a variable to determine which radio button is clicked

```
function displayType(def) {
  var checked = def === '3d';

  document.getElementById('animation').disabled = checked; 
}
```

HTML, pass a variable to the javascript function indicating whether its 3d or 2d thats clicked

```
<input type="radio" name="pipelineType" value="2d" id="2d" checked="checked" onclick="displayType('2d')"> 2D Pipleline <br>
<input type="radio" name="pipelineType" value="3d" id="3d" onclick="displayType('3d')"> 3D Pipleline </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution,

1. remove `<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="createProject">` and its closing tag.
2. Change your code from  onclick="displayType" to onclick="displayType()" in first two radio buttons.